# Is it necessary that X is also regular?

Tags: regular-language

Given that $L$ is a regular language and $X \subseteq L$,does $X$ have to be also regular?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. $\Sigma^\ast$ is regular, but not all $L \subseteq \Sigma^\ast$ are regular.

Comment: Could you give me a counterexample?

Comment: The language $\{ 0^i 1^i \mid i \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is not regular. You can show this using the pumping lemma.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I have also an other question..Do I have to write which is the $\Sigma$ of the language,or is it enough to say that $\Sigma^{*}$ is a regular language and $\{0^i1^i|i \in N\} \subseteq \Sigma^{*}$??

Comment: As long as $0$ and $1$ are in $\Sigma$.